# Code smell - passing boolean control argument to function

Tags: javascript, dom, refactoring, readability

Below is the code fragment, there is something which I don't like:

```
function insert(el, child, before){
  if ( before ) {
    el.insertBefore(child, el.childNodes[0]);
  } else {
    el.appendChild(child);
  }
}
```

Why not instead have two separate methods like `insertBefore` and `insertAfter`? what are the pros and cons of this and other approach?

**Update:**

I got this nice [article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1392524) explaining what I wanted.

Comment: What's the purpose of this question? You have a code you don't like?? Change it!

Comment: @Amit the purpose of this question is writing better code. The definition of better being easy to understand and test. I think question together with tags clarify the intent properly.

Comment: What's the purpose of this function? why don't you simply use appendChild, for example? Is this part of some lib?

Comment: @Thomas yes, its a public lib [here](https://github.com/kenwheeler/cash/blob/master/src/manipulation.js).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole purpose of this function is to avoid having to put an `if` statement in all the places where you call the function. So if you have lots of places that look like:

```
if (something) {
    foo.insertBefore(bar, foo.childNodes[0]));
} else {
    foo.appendChild(bar);
}
```

You can simplify all of them to:

```
insert(foo, bar, something);
```

With your two methods, it would become:

```
if (something) {
    insertBefore(foo, bar);
} else {
    insertAfter(foo, bar);
}
```

which isn't too much better than the original.

Comment: But it requires client code to remember to pass that flag each time it calls that method, moreover I would know whether I have to insert before or after in my client code no need to have if conditions scattered throughout my code.

Comment: You would only use this method when the choice needs to be determined dynamically. It's like why jQuery has both `hide`, `show`, and `toggle`. You use `toggle` when it's dynamic, and `hide/show` when it's known a priori.